# LilyPond: Indicate alternate endings

Tags: lilypond, repeats

Using LilyPond, I would like to indicate alternate endings to the piece I am engraving; an "Optional 'Screen Gems' Ending" which is 2 measures long or another "Low Fat" ending (not my terms; they are in the original score) which is 1 measure.  I would like notation similar to 1st and 2nd endings but without the repeat, of course.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

See [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/long-repeats) for the LilyPond documentation on [long repeats](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/long-repeats#manual-repeat-marks).

```
\version "2.24.0"

voltaFirst = \markup \text "Gems"
voltaSecond = \markup \text "Fat"

\relative {
  e'4 e e e
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta voltaFirst))
  g2 g g g \bar "||"
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #(list(list 'volta voltaSecond))
  d1
  \set Score.repeatCommands = #'((volta #f))
  \bar "|."
}
```

[image: Text other than numbers in repeats]

You can add usual markup arguments after `\text` to change how it's displayed.

Comment: This seems kind of ridiculously complicated to me. :-/

Comment: It's not much more complicated than what's written in their documentation.

Comment: Not criticising you, just commenting on the code. Sorry for the miscommunication.